# Backbone View With Multiple Collections

Tags: backbone.js, syntax, subview, backbone.js-collections, listen

I defined the two collections in my app.js file like this:

```
 this.shoppingCartFullPageView.collections = {
    supplyCategoriesCollection: this.supplyCategoriesCollection,
    orderedSuppliesCollection: this.orderedSuppliesCollection
}
```

Here is the code for my view:

```
var ShoppingCartFullPageView = Backbone.View.extend ({
    initialize: function () {
    this.listenTo(this.collection, "reset", this.render);
    },

    render: function() {
        $(this.el).html(new ShoppingCartListView ({
            collection: this.collections.supplyCategoriesCollection
        }).render().el);

        $(this.el).append(new OrderedSupplyListView ({
            collection: this.collections.orderedSuppliesCollection  
        }).render().el);

        return this;
    }
});
```

I have a Backbone View that is rendering subviews that each have their own collection. The two subviews are rendering correctly. The problem is in the initialize function.
The code above listens to "reset" on both collections. I want to "listenTo" the "reset" on only one of the collections. When I try "this.listenTo(this.collections.supplyCategoriesCollection, "reset", this.render);" i get an undefined error.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Are your collections initialized?

How about this:

```
this.shoppingCartFullPageView.collections = {
    supplyCategoriesCollection: new this.supplyCategoriesCollection(),
    orderedSuppliesCollection: new this.orderedSuppliesCollection()
}
```

Comment: ShoppingCartListView is already listening to the collection correctly. The problem is that ShoppingCartFullPageView is listening to this.collections.supplyCategoriesCollection AND this.collections.orderedSuppliesCollection. I want it to listen to the former only.

Comment: @Sizzles27 I updated my answer. The undefined error could be because you have not yet initialized your collections.